# How to comment why a catch can be ignored

Tags: c#, sonarqube

I am getting a message on Sonar:

> Handle the exception or explain in a comment why it can be ignored.

How do I get rid off this warning by providing a comment explaining to ignore this?

I am using C# for coding and my catch block  is `catch {}`

```
catch
{
 // handled globally
}
finally
{
 connection.Close()
}
```

Catch code and on finally block I have added some code to close connection.

Comment: Did you try putting a comment inside or above the catch and see if either of those worked to suppress the message? If so, put what you tried (always do it in SO questions so people don’t suggest you to do stuff you already tried), if not.. maybe try it and see if it stops you needing to post the question :)

Comment: In Visual Studio you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>.</kbd> on the catch line. In the context menu you can select to surpress this warning for this line, file or project.

Comment: @oliver though it seems a reasonable warning, and it doesn’t mean some part of the build process will later succeed elsewhere (maybe they have warnings as errors active on the build server, maybe the house rule is not to modify the code analysis rule sets, etc)

Comment: @CaiusJard updated the question with what i have done now

Comment: I'd look carefully at whatever `connection` is and see if it implements `IDisposable`. Always prefer using `using` statements over manually re-implementing them via `try`/`finally`. If it's your own class and doesn't currently implement `IDisposable`, that would also be the recommended way to go.

Comment: In C#, I use :: try { } catch(Exception) { } finally { } to avoid the warning of an unused variable and the error of not catching anything.

Answer (score 4):

That exception isn’t handled globally, it’s thrown away. You should use a pattern of:

```
try{
  //code
}
finally {
  //close connection
}
```

This removes the warning from Sonar and makes your apparent intentions true (that the global handler will deal with the exception) otherwise you’re just going to silently lose every error this code throws which will cause your help desk team no end of joy

I’ve declined to answer the question as stated for this reason, but the answer you seek is in Sonar’s fine manual if you desperately want to go that route; it *will* bite you

Answer (score 0):

Below is your original code. The comment inside the `catch` block is bit confusing. The catch block in the code snippet is either a global exception handler or it is not. So let's understand both the cases in detail.

```
catch
{
    //handled globally
}
finally
{
    connection.Close()
}
```

`catch` block in the code above is a catch-all exception block i.e. generic exception handler for all kinds of exceptions. Above is an alternate/shortcut way of writing:

```
catch(Exception ex)
{
    //Generic exception handler: Eat all excetion here.
}
finally
{
    connection.Close()
}
```

You're handling an exception but not dealing with it in any way e.g. logging the exception details in a file. That's why Sonar is complaining with the error that you've mentioned. To overcome the warning you can do either of two approaches based on your condition:

1. **Do not handle exception (Not a global exception handler)**: If you do not want to handle the exception then remove the catch block or rethrow the exception explicitly. This happens when there is already a global exception handler somewhere else which will handle the exception when it bubbles up the call stack :

   ```
   try{
         //code
   }
   finally {
       //close connection
   }
   ```

   OR

   ```
   catch(Exception ex)
   {
       //bubble up the exception for global exception handler
       throw ex;
   }
   finally
   {
       connection.Close()
   }
   ```

   OR

   ```
   catch(Exception)
   {
       //bubble up the exception for global exception handler
       throw;
   }
   finally
   {
       connection.Close()
   }
   ```
2. **Logging (Global exception handler)**: Add a log statement inside the catch block as shown in the code-snippet below:

   ```
   catch(Exception ex)
   {
       Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
       //throw ex; //optionally you can rethrow the exception even after logging it if you catch block is not a global exception handler
   }
   finally
   {
       connection.Close()
   }
   ```

   The log statement inside `catch` block gives an indication to Sonar that we're dealing with the exception and hence suppresses the warning.